# Change Add to cart button text to Added when product already in cart and product tag is buynow

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the add to cart text to **Added** when product is already in cart and change the add to cart button text to **Buy Now** when product tag is buynow.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Change the add to cart text on single product pages
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text');
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $woocommerce;    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            //return __('&#10003; Added', 'woocommerce');
            return __('Added', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }

    //return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce');
    if ( has_term( 'buynow', 'product_tag', $_product->id ) ) :
            return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
        else:
            return __( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' );
        endif;
}
/**
 * Change the add to cart text on product archives
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );
function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $woocommerce;    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if( get_the_ID() == $_product->ID ) {

            //return __('&#10003; Added', 'woocommerce');
            return __('Added', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }

    //return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce');
    if ( has_term( 'buynow', 'product_tag', $_product->ID ) ) :
            return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
        else:
            return __( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' );
        endif;
}
```

My code works perfectly for single product page but not for product archive page.

Anyone have solution/suggestion for this please share. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` instead of `ID` for the object `$_product`!

Try to use `var_dump()` to see what values are compared. You would have seen that `$_product->ID` was empty.

Comment: It returns the added when the product is in cart but can not return Buy Now , when the product tag is "buynow" in product archive page

Comment: It happens both for single page and product archive page. I logical mistake I think. Can you please help me @santerref

Answer (score 0):

Finally Its working

Here is the code I put in woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php

```
global $product;

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            $incart[] = $_product->id;
        }
    }
if (in_array($product->id, $incart, true)) {
    $output = 'Added';
}elseif(in_array($product->id, $incart, true) && has_term( 'buynow', 'product_tag', $_product->id )){
     $output = 'Added';
}elseif ( has_term( 'buynow', 'product_tag', $product->id ) ){
    $output = 'Buy Now';
}else{
$output = 'Add to cart';
}
```